# a .get() request on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I will be redirecting the user to a page. This page gets all of its content from a REST api in JSON format. So on page load I would like to execute the `$.get()` request and load the contents of my divs in the page.

I know how to execute the `get` request, however, I don't know how to do it on page load. I have a `application.js` file for my entire application. So I can't put it in `document.ready` because that it would load on each page in my application.

I will be executing the `get` request like this:

```
$.get(
  $(this).data('myurl'),
  function (data) {
    var item = data.response.item[0];
    $('mydiv').html(item.text);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add it as an inline script block with a separate document.ready, or just before `</body>`.

Or add it to a separate js file, and link it only from the specific page where you want to use it.

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery this is very easy, but you have to put this block in your 'start'-page:

```
$(function() {
  // this code will be executed on page load
  app.start();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you only want to get data from rest api on a specific page..

for that you can do:

```
$(function(){
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('/your/page/url') > -1){
        // your $.get here
        $.get('/torestapi', function(){ //update divs });
    }
});
```

Comment: and then rename the page and search for hours why it doesn't work anymore :)